# How do I copy a keyframe for settings across multiple objects?

Tags: physics, keyframes, graph-editor

I can change the physics properties of all the objects in my scene at the same time, by selecting them all then hitting ALT when I make changes in the Physics properties. Or I can copy the values of an object onto all others via Object - Rigid Body - Copy from Active. But neither of these will add keyframes of selection properties in the Physics tab. Such as 'Dynamic' or 'Animated'.

If I want an object to drop at a certain keyframe, I can tick the Dynamics setting in the physics tab and keyframe it. But I cannot copy and paste that keyframe to all of the physics properties of all the other objects. I have to laboriously change them one at a time. And I have hundreds!

I've tried adding the keyframe by tapping 'I', but that does not show any relevant options.

If I open the graph editor, I can find the keyframe I added for 'Dynamic' or 'Animated' there, but again, there are no options to copy that keyframe to all the other objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK with vanilla Blender you can copy one keyframe to another/one object, but not to multiple objects. I think there might be add-ons somewhere who could these things.

You mismatch two things here: properties (like location, rotation) and animation data.

These are two totally different things (data-blocks) in Blender.

What you can do - but i think you won't like it - you can "link" your animation data to other objects, so that they "share" the same animation data (and with same, i mean the same) - so if e.g. they have location data animated, all these objects would have the same location which in most cases make no sense.
But it can make sense to first link the animations (because all objects have a lot of animated properties which are the same) and (maybe) only a very few animated location data which are different. You can link animation data with CTRL-L (->link animation data) so that all selected objects will get the same animation data as your last selected object. Whenever you now make a change of animation data (e.g. move a keyframe in graph editor) all other objects will be affected too.
After linking the animation data you can make the animation data so called "single-user" again (object->relation->make single user) which means: now they don't share the animation data anymore but they got an "own" real copy of it so if you change any keyframe of that object - no other object will be affected.